# Given three positive numbers $a,b,c$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b+1}}\geqq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\,abc}{3\,abc+1}}$ .

Tags: inequality, substitution, holder-inequality, uvw, muirhead-inequality

> *Ji Chen.* Given three positive numbers $a, b, c$. Prove that
>   $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+ b}{b+ 1}}\geqq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\,abc}{3\,abc+ 1}}$$

Of course, we've to solve it by $uvw$, before that, I tried to use *Holder-inequality* with integer polynomials but without a high probability of success for me against this particular problem ...

I found here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h538065p3209975, something obvious

Comment: What is $uvw$ ?

Comment: $uvw$ is a very useful method for the proof of polynomial inequalities with three variables. Sometimes it works for more variables as well. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b+1}}\geq3\sqrt[6]{\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{a+1}}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)(3abc+1)^2\geq16a^2b^2c^2(a+1)(b+1)(c+1).$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$(9uv^2-w^3)(3w^3+1)^2\geq16w^6(w^3+3v^2+3u+1)$$ and since by AM-GM $uv^2\geq w^3,$ it's enough to prove that
$$uv^2(3w^3+1)^2\geq2w^6(w^3+3v^2+3u+1),$$ which is true by AM-GM.

Indeed, by AM-GM $$2w^6(w^3+3v^2+3u+1)=2w^9+6v^2w^6+6uw^6+2w^6\leq$$
$$\leq2uv^2w^6+6uv^2w^5+6uv^2w^4+2uv^2w^3$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$(3w^3+1)^2\geq2w^6+6w^5+6w^4+2w^3$$ or
$$(3w^3+1)^2\geq2w^3(w+1)^3.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: This was no modest one, but you defeated easily enough. What style !

Comment: Could you tell more about the last step AM-GM ?

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you, it is equivalent to $(w-1)^2.f(w)\ge 0$

Comment: Sorry, but it is very helpful if you help me gave expanding expression. $$(ab+bc+ca)\left[(a+b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca\right]^3 \ge 3\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{(a+b)^3(a+c)^3(2b^2+5bc+2c^2)},$$I think I found something nice.

Comment: It's $\sum\limits_{sym}(a^7b+3a^6b^2-3a^4b^4+2a^6bc+3a^5b^2c-3a^4b^3c-3a^3b^3c^2)\geq0,$ which is obvious by Muirhead.

Comment: Thank you. I saw you used Holder a beautiful and I tried.